# NYX Doesn't run

Tags: nyx

I'm installing a bridge on a new droplet. Small issue with torrc; couldn't bind to control port. Forgot relay was on control port 9050 so changed to 9055. Now torrc is happy.

NYX is not. 
sudo apt-get install nyx: without complaint from Ubuntu. Below is what I get when I enter nyx or debian-tor:

It's always something!

Adriann

PS- Thanks much for any help :-)
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

File "/usr/bin/nyx", line 11, in 
    load_entry_point('nyx==2.0.4', 'console_scripts', 'nyx')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2693, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nyx/**init**.py", line 46, in 
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'

Comment: Got it!!!   sudo apt-get install python3-distutils :-)

Answer (score 0):

As @adriann said in the comments, the following command should do the job:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```